# CSS SVG text-shadow is on top of text

Tags: html, css, svg

I am simply trying to put a shadow behind some text, but the shadow seems to be displayed on top of the text instead. I'm using Google Chrome. This is an image:

[image: image of shadow inside text]

Here it is, rendered in your browser:

```css
#title {
  fill: white;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 3px black;
  font-size: 400%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-weight: bold;
  stroke: #F08000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<svg style="background:rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2); width:100%; height:calc(20vh + 20px); margin:auto; display:block;">
   <text id="title" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="20vh">Software</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: That looks like a very unique bug. Best use an SVG filter to do the shadow.

Comment: Does it need to use the SVG tag?

Comment: I need the svg tag to create a good outline for the text that works across the most common browsers.  It does seem to be the problem, but I need it more than the shadow.

Answer (score 5):

Decrease horizontal and vertical shadows and increase blur radius in text-shadow property:

```
text-shadow: 6px 6px 10px black;
```

Here's the working sample: [Check Me!](https://jsfiddle.net/mytest_jsfiddle/3dp90ec9/)

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This doesn't really _fix_ it, it just makes it less noticeable. If I were to make the shadow darker, this wouldn't work as well.  Although, it may be what I use in the end.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what's happening is that for some reason the shadow for the stroke is being applied on top of the fill color (I'm not sure why things would be layered like that, but it seems to be the case).  A workaround would be to create two `<text>` elements, one just to make the shadow, and another to go on top of it.

HTML:

```
<svg style="background:rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2); width:100%; height:calc(20vh + 20px); margin:auto; display:block;">
   <text id="titleshadow" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="20vh">Software</text>
   <text id="titletop" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="20vh">Software</text>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
text {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   font-size: 400%;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: consolas;
   font-weight: bold;
}
#titleshadow {
   text-shadow: 10px 10px 3px black;
}
#titletop {  
   stroke: #F08000;
   stroke-width: 1px;
   fill: #fff;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wquzq9z4/

Comment: CSS properties, such as `margin` and `text-align` are not valid for SVG  elements. The `display: block` is pointless here also.

Comment: I was mostly just copying what was in the OP, but thanks for the info.

Comment: Why does the text go off the screen on Edge and IE?